# HTML novice - video and table interfering

Tags: html, css

So im making my very first website for myself. I want a mp4 video with a table just off to the right hand side of the video. I've got them each working seperately but dont work together.

i.e when the video code is in place the table just disapears. Im not good at explaining this so ill just let you guys have a look for yourself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
body {margin:0;}


ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;    
}

li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {border-right: none;}

li a {
display: block;
padding: 14px 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #808080;
border: 1px solid black;
}
table, td, th {border: 1px solid black;}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 50%;
}

th {
text-align: center;
height: 25px;
color:white;
background-color: #808080;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}

td{text-align: left;}

th, td {
padding:15px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home\home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile\profile.html">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#matches">Matches</a></li>
  <li><a href="#highlights">Highlights</a></li>
  <li><a href="#setup">Setup</a></li>
  <li><a href="#shop">Shop</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul><br>
<hr>

<video width="200" height"500" autoplay loop>
    <source src="promo.mp4" type="video/mp4"
</video>
<hr><br>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table align="right">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Birth</th>
        <th>Nationality</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Total Winnings</th>
        <th>Game(s)</th>
        <th>Past Teams</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>qwerty</td>
        <td>wqert</td>
        <td>wqer</td>
        <td>wqer</td>
        <td>qwer</td>
        <td>qwer</td>
        <td>qwer</td>
        <td>qwer</td>
        <td>qwer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Im sure theres alot of rookie mistakes in there which is expected, dont be too harsh :)
I realise that the video wont show up on your end but maybe use a random mp4 of your own?
Thanks regardless.

Comment: Take all your HTML and enter it into the [W3C HTML Checker](https://checker.html5.org/#textarea). View all your errors and correct them. There are 15 at a minimum. Then come back.

Answer (score -2):

I transformed your code into the fiddle below to try it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/fmmnsw04/1/

**UPDATE:**  Rather than a horizontal rule `<hr />` tag I would use a `<div>` with a top and bottom border instead because you'll have better control over appearance like margins, colors, and widths.

I think one of one of the styles that was contributing to the layout problems was that the ul had position:fixed;

I updated the fiddle so the video and table appear side by side. Here is the portion that demonstrates a solution for that requirement:

```
.datawrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.videodata,
.tabledata {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.videodata {
  width: 40%;
}
.videodata video {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.tabledata {
  width: 60%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
  <div class="datawrapper">
    <div class="videodata">
      <video width="100%" controls="controls">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your 

browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="tabledata">
      <table>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: awesome thanks, ill give it ago. much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to web design! If you find this helpful please accept the answer and/or upvote.

Comment: First, W3Schools, which you link to, has no affiliation whatsoever with the W3C and are totally unrelated in any way, shape or form. Second, `<br />` is an XHTML construct and not specified in any HTML specification ever. Though it is valid, it is ignored, means nothing, is pointless and, therefore, useless. And, third,  it's W3C, not WC3.

Comment: Also, the `<hr>` **element** was NOT removed from the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element

Comment: Thanks but this isnt quite what i was after. I want the table to be DIRECTLY adjacent to the video. Ive tried to use z-index: -1; but this only works till the video plays and then the table moves down. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rob Okay, I might have made a mistake or two but was the attitude and down vote really needed? I revised my answer so are you happy now?

Comment: You are required to post code for your answer here. Not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: @jomot [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) z-index specifies the stack order (e.g. layering) of elements.  I updated my answer and fiddle so the video and table are side by side.  A combination of div.datawrapper and child float divs can satisfy your requirement.  I also include a border and margin to div.datawrapper.